# statements and implications involving limits in complex plane

Tags: complex-analysis, limits, derivatives

I have two statements, and I am working in the complex plane:

(1): $\underset{w\rightarrow z}{lim}g(w)=0$

(2): $\underset{w\rightarrow z}{lim}\frac{g(w)}{w-z}=0$

I want to know which one implies the other.
I am pretty sure that (2)->(1), however I am having difficulties proving it.

I started by assuming (2). I then rewrite (2) using the limit law for fractions and get:

$\frac{\underset{w\rightarrow z}{lim}g(w)}{\underset{w\rightarrow z}{lim}w-z}=0$.

Now, I know that $\underset{w\rightarrow z}{lim}(w-z)=0$ but now can i conclude anything:

$\frac{\underset{w\rightarrow z}{lim}g(w)}{0}=0$   ?

I was thinking going the contrapositive way and assuming that (1) is false. This would imply that $\underset{w\rightarrow z}{lim}g(w)\neq0$ and therefore $\frac{\underset{w\rightarrow z}{lim}g(w)}{\underset{w\rightarrow z}{lim}w-z}=\infty$.

any suggestions ?

Also,a counterexample of some function g that satisfies (1) and not (2) would be most helpful...

Comment: $g(w) = {g(w) \over w-z} (w-z)$ hence you can show that (2) implies (1). Try $g(w) = w-z$ to show that (1) does not imply (2).

Comment: ouh I see, thanks a lot. I knew it was a small trick that was escaping me!

Comment: That took me 30 years of education :-).